# infinite scrolling on data from database

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need help to populate the the drop down with infinite scrolling. I have created a normal dropdown in which all the data goes but it takes a lot of time to load the data. Here is my code.

```
function GetSelectedWorldList(){

   var el = $('#<%=lstAvail.ClientID%>');
    var selValues = [
    <asp:Repeater ID="lstSelect" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    '<%# Eval("slc_code")%>'
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
    ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    ];
    console.log(selValues);
    $(el).select2("val", selValues);


}
```

Comment: You won't be able to do this with a normal `<select>`.  You're currently calling `.select2()` which is not defined in your question, so might be possible using whatever plugin that uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look at loading the data in via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) rather than loading it all in at once.

You can then make your initial query select less data, which depending on your sql maybe quicker (note if doing a top 10 with order by may still be slow). When you need more data you will make an AJAX call to another Url that returns the extra data. This can then be received and added to the page.

At it's most basic it would be something like this sample from https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/ although there are also libraries and more efficient ways:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var win = $(window);

    // Each time the user scrolls
    win.scroll(function() {
        // End of the document reached?
        if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
            $('#loading').show();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'get-post.aspx',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#posts').append(html);
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```